# improving SegNet segmentation performance

Tags: neural-network, caffe

I have trained a segmentation net for images using caffe by [SegNet tutorial](http://mi.eng.cam.ac.uk/projects/segnet/tutorial.html#references). For each `.jpg` image having dimension `3x256x256`, I have a `256x256` ground truth `.png` image. I have `2 classes` (object and background).
As you can see in the image I got pretty good results. but I got a background noises as well - the week color-pixels dots that surrounding the main segmentation pixels.

I want to remove those background noises, s0 the segmentation will be clear as possible. what should I change/add in the net architecture? How exactly should I tackle this problem ? thanks for helping.

[image]

Comment: what is the input image?

Comment: consider adding graphcut segmentation on top?

Comment: In your learning set you should accurately annotate object area. If there are background pixels mistakenly comes under object class in learning set it might give such results

Comment: @Shai my input images are .jpg images with unclear background with 1 or more objects. and my ground truth images are .png images with clear(!!!) background (when I say clear I mean 1 color), with 1 color object/s that I create via original object/s quads. as I said before, 2 classes. thanks

Comment: @Shai for example, I want to recognise a window. so I made a huge training set with lot of images that have a window and a background (not clear as you can see in this image example, and I made a ground truth set with clear background and one color object (with window quads). how can I improve the accuracy and remove the "pixels noise"? thanks
The Image is:
<img src="http://www.walldevil.com/wallpapers/a30/composite-spring-wallpapers-digital-background-papers-wallpaper-objects-art.jpg" width="100" height="100">